# Interface props in functional components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using the nightly-build of TypeScript (Version 1.9.0-dev.20160218), and trying to work out if there is any way to use static typed props in my functional react component.

The current code seems to give no compile errors, and works just fine. But as I have set the `myvar` to be of type Number, but actually assign it as a String I would have expected a compile-time error.

Does TypeScript currently support strict-types for props in functional components, or only for classes?

```
interface Props extends React.Props {
    mynumber: Number
}

var MyComponent = (props: Props) => {
    return <p>My variable: {props.mynumber}</p>;
};

var MyContainer = () => {
    const mystring:String = '123';
    return <MyComponent myvar={mystring}/>
};
```

Comment: Are you including `react.d.ts` in your compilation?

Comment: yes, if I didn't I would get compile-time errors. Everything seems to work - but the problem is that it shouldnt. I am clearly using wrong types, but when I run the application it just shows a paragraph with the text "123", no errors.

Comment: It sounds like you need to update your react.d.ts file -- if you were up-to-date, you'd be seeing an error at line 1 (React.Props is generic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code works as expected:

```
/// <reference path="../DefinitelyTyped/react/react.d.ts" />

import * as React from 'react';

interface Props extends React.Props<any> {
    mynumber: Number
}

var MyComponent = (props: Props) => {
    return <p>My variable: {props.mynumber}</p>;
};

var MyContainer = () => {
    const mystring:String = '123';
    return <MyComponent myvar={mystring}/>
};
```

> test.tsx(15,12): error TS2324: Property 'mynumber' is missing in type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.
>   test.tsx(15,25): error TS2339: Property 'myvar' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.

It looks like you have an outdated react.d.ts, or something else is wrong and your code sample isn't representative.

As an aside, *never* use `String` or `Number`. These aren't the types you want -- use `string` and `number`, respectively

Comment: found the error, I was using tsify to build the code (should have written that in my question). It used an old compiler for typescript. Making sure tsify used the nightly-build of typescript solved the problem.

I will give you accepted as you pointed me in the right direction.