# Which type props have in functional components of react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-props

I need to pass react component props to another component like:

```
interface IMyComponent {
    props: Props<any>
}

const MyComponent: FC = ({ props }) => {
}
```

As you can see I was trying to use React.Props type after reading this question:
[Interface props in functional components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35492273/interface-props-in-functional-components)

But now is 2021 and I use
"react": "^17.0.1" and "typescript": "^4.1.3"
and I get a message that React.Props is deprecated.

Which type should I use for props?

Also I would be thankful to get a link to a handbook where I can find types for anything in React, because now it is extremely hard to detect the type of some React things and React docs has no examples in Typescript. That is a pain.

Comment: *because now it is extremely hard to detect the type of some React things and React docs has no examples in Typescript. That is a pain.* - just check typing source files. It's always like that in TS.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do them [like in this code snippet](https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react-why-i-dont-use-react-fc/#what%E2%80%99s-react.fc%3C%3E%3F). Basically creating your own type which you pass in the React.FC and in it defining the type for each property.